# probability that C lies inside the circle with diameter AB is 1/4.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Q.(from a book)

> The six coordinates $(X_i , Y_i ), i = 1,2,3$, of three points $A, B, C$ in the plane are independent $N(0,1)$. Show that the the probability that $C$ lies inside the circle with diameter $AB$ is $1/4$.

I was trying to approach this in terms of area :
The probability that C lies inside the circle will be = E(area of circle)/E(total Area).
where E is expectation.

I can calculate the numerator by taking expectations and it comes out as pi.
I dont know how to calculate the denominator and the intuition for it is also unclear.
For ex : if the distribution was say U(-1,1) then denominator makes perfect sense and you can calculate it mentally but for N(0,1) its unclear. Any ideas?

Comment: Even if you managed to compute something here, this strategy will not work in principle. The probability of landing in a circle is determined by the area of the circle only when the point is uniformly placed. For a normally distributed point C, the probability that C lands in a circle only depends on the area of that circle.

Comment: In principle, the condition $AB^2 > AC^2 + BC^2$ might be a good way to check the circle condition, but the computation does not seem straightforward.

Comment: yes. It is indeed very clear for uniform. But i was thinking that normal is just weighted uniform and so the probabilities will be "adjusted" anyways based on mean and variance.

Comment: Sorry, that comment should say "the probability that $C$ lands in a circle **does not** only depend on the area of that circle". A circle far from the origin is less likely to contain $C$. So you cannot only compute the expected value of the area and expect that to tell you anything.

Comment: @MishaLavrov It actually is reasonably straightforward, but tedious if done directly: There's an appropriate rotation of the coordinate system in which the condition is of the form $u_1^2+v_1^2<3(u_2^2+v_2^2)$. At that point the integrals are simple enough to do by hand. (But the simplicity of the answer suggests this isn't the cleverest approach.)

Comment: This might be relevant since we are interested in the probability of the triangle between acute: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-9/issue-2/A-Lewis-Carroll-Pillow-Problem--Probability-of-an-Obtuse/10.1214/ss/1177010497.full